# How can ASCII representation of binary data be smaller than the binary representation?

Tags: python, sockets, binary, byte, ascii

I was reading a page from Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#binary-data) related to sockets and I came a across this mysterious(for me) paragraph:

> In these days of 64-bit machines, the ASCII representation of binary
> data is frequently smaller than the binary representation. That’s
> because a surprising amount of the time, most integers have the value
> 0, or maybe 1. The string "0" would be two bytes, while a full 64-bit
> integer would be 8. Of course, this doesn’t fit well with fixed-length
> messages. Decisions, decisions.

As a former Biomedical Engineer who doesn't have computer science background, I couldn't really get it("sorry in advance if it's too obvious to you"). In fact My main questions are:

1. Why did it say: *"The string "0" would be two bytes"*? Doesn't it use one byte? ASCII uses 7 bits of a byte.

```py
char = "0"
print(len(char.encode("ascii")))  # 1
```

2. Why did it say: *the ASCII representation of binary data is frequently smaller than the binary representation*? Suppose I want to send number `200`. in binary: I can easily use 1 byte to represent it in binary but with ASCII I should use 3:

```py
number = 200
print(len(number.to_bytes(1, "big")))   # 1
print(len(str(number).encode("ascii"))) # 3
```

3. Why did it say: *"a surprising amount of the time, most integers have the value 0, or maybe 1"*: Why is that? What kind of data is he/she dealing with that mostly contains zeros and ones and not 3 for example.
4. *"a full 64-bit integer would be 8"*, Is it because we should always send a [*word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) to the network and not just bytes? Isn't it wasting bandwidths? Isn't it possible with delimiters?

Comment: 1) I don't know why it say 2 bytes for the string, perhaps they're assuming a null byte string end delimiter, 2 and 4) the paragraph is about sending binary data, presumably the protocol reserves 64 bits for the integer and so you must always send 64 bits, and you use can't be a delimiter because any potential delimiter byte just looks like part of the number. But you could use a different protocol that sends a compressed integer for example, 3) I'm sure they're just talking about characteristics observed over a large range of unrelated programs, and specific program will be different.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Great. Thank you for your attention. I got what I should get from your comment.